# how to generate a textfield with customized height (yii textField)

Tags: css, yii

Hello everybody and thanks for reading. 
I have this

```
   <?php
                echo $form->textField($model, 'link', array(
                    'prepend' => '<i class="icon-4x icon-globe" style="line-height: 54px;"></i>',
                    'class' => 'span12', 'maxlength' => 999, 
                    'height'=>100, 
                    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'height:60px;font-size: 22px;')
                    ));
                ?>
```

This is not working for width but when i replace it with height its not working. There is no other css rules that overwrite it . 
How can i set a custom height on a textfiled in yii

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from  [yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#textField-detail):

```
public string textField(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

so you should have:

```
$form->textfield($model,'link',array('style'=>'width:600px;'));
```

i see that you also have a class:

```
$form->textfield($model,'link',array('style'=>'width:600px;', 'class' => 'class_x'));
```

now, let me explin what happens within your code:

```
echo $form->textField($model, 'link', array(
                    'prepend' => '<i class="icon-4x icon-globe" style="line-height: 54px;"></i>',
                    'class' => 'span12', 'maxlength' => 999, 
                    'height'=>100, 
                    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'height:60px;font-size: 22px;')
                    ));
```

the first and second parameters are ok

when it comes to the 3rd one, at first it looks fine, because it is a array, that represents the htmlOptions array from the documentation

if you digg deeper, you see that in the htmlOptions array you have another htmlOptions array; WHY?

write like this:

```
echo $form->textField($model, 'link', array(
                    'prepend' => '<i class="icon-4x icon-globe" style="line-height: 54px;"></i>',
                    'class' => 'span12',
                    'style' => 'height:60px;font-size: 22px;width:999px;',
                    ));
```

Comment: This answer is correct apart from an error at `'style'=>'width:600px'` in the 2nd and 3rd code blocks

Comment: yeah, thanks, i was in a hurry, just leaving the office when i saw this article; fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
echo $form->textField($model,'link',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,));
```