# How do I add inline css to dropdown in Yii?

Tags: php, css, yii

This is my code:

```
 <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'type', CHtml::listData($ab->type, 'id', 'name'), array('class' => 'edit'), array('width:165px')); ?>
```

I am trying to add inline css to my dropdown, but my example does not work. Why ?

Comment: Have you try this: array('style' => 'width:165px')

Comment: I tried, but still does not work

Comment: Ok..and this?  array('class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'width:165px')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'type', CHtml::listData($ab->type, 'id', 'name'), array('class' => 'edit', 'style' => 'width:165px')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573945/how-to-generate-a-textfield-with-customized-height-yii-textfield)

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'type', CHtml::listData($ab->type, 'id', 'name'), array('class' => 'edit', 'style'=>'width:165px;')); ?
```

Comment: It's better to vote up previous answer than posting exactly identical answer.